# `@RabbitListener` `@SendTo` Reply Not Working When Returning a `org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>`

Tags: spring-amqp

I've been successfully using a method that returns my business object with an `@RabbitListener` annotation.

The registered `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` bean named `messageConverter` kicks in and perfectly converts both the incoming JSON message to my expected type and the returned business object to JSON.

```
// This works!!
@RabbitListener(...)
@SendTo("#{responseDestination})
MyBusinessResponseObject handle(MyBusinessRequestObject request) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

But now, when I start returning a `org.springframework.messageing.Message<MyBusinessResponseObject>`, then I get exceptions in the logs saying: `SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.domain.MyBusinessResponseObject`

```
// This DOESN'T work
@RabbitListener(...)
@SendTo("#{responseDestination})
Message<MyBusinessResponseObject> handle(MyBusinessRequestObject request) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

I've tried explicitly referencing my `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` in the `@RabbitLisener` annotation's `containerFactory` property, but I still get the same error.

I'm not sure why a `SimpleMessageConverter` is kickking in in this case and where it is coming from.

How do I override that message converter that is being used to convert my new return type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug; please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Looks like the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter` has to override a `setMessageConverter()` and propagate an argument to the `MessagingMessageConverter.payloadConverter` property.